# How can I decrease App size after integrated here map SDK?

Tags: sdk, here-api

My App size increase about 50M after integrated here map SDK, it is too large for me, can I do something to decrease the App size? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow our documentation linked [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/size-management.html) for and Android [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/size-management.html)  for iOS. You can safely remove some of the font files if you do not require showing the map for Chinese, or other South Asian languages.